# How to make a VBA input box that only disappears if the user enters a 7 character code with 3 numbers and an "M" and an "!"

Tags: vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to create a password-like input box that has parameters. There can only be 7 characters, 3 of which are numbers and one which is an "B" and one which is an "?". I am stuck on figuring out how to get the three numbers right now and any help would be appreciated.
Here's what i have so far

```
Sub btn_CheckCode2()
Dim code As String
code = InputBox("Enter a Code")
Dim threenumbers As Boolean
threenumbers = False

Do Until code <> "" And Len(code) = 7 And threenumbers = True
If IsNumeric(Right(code, 1)) = True And IsNumeric(Right(code, 2)) = True And IsNumeric(Right(code, 3)) = True Then
threenumbers = True

code = InputBox("Enter a Code")
IsNumeric(code) = True
Loop


MsgBox ("Thank you for entering " & code)
End Sub
```

Comment: You should learn to properly indent your code, It makes it much easier to read and understand, and to follow the flow of execution. Learning now before you get used to bad habits will be much easier, and you'll learn to understand at some point why the proper indentation is much better.

Comment: Also, your code assumes the rightmost three characters are numbers. Why are you using three separate calls to `IsNumeric` and `Right`, instead of just using one like `IsNumeric(Right(code, 3))`, or just grab them and convert to an integer and check for a value > 99 and < 1000?

Comment: I did this because my plan was to check each one since there has to be 3 in the code but it does not matter which 3. Then I realized I would have to use a ton of coding and Or statements to make this work and I feel like there's a better way. Thanks for the feedback though!!

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string to array of bytes using [StrConv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strconv-function) then loop through the array and do a count if the value is within 48 - 57 (which is number 0 -9) ([Reference](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/strings-characters/ascii-characters.htm)), if the count is 3 then it should means there are 3 numbers in the input.

We can apply similar concept to check for 1 instance of "B" and 1 instance of "!". The function `InputValid` does the above and you can then use it in your loop to validate the input like this:

```
Sub btn_CheckCode2()
    Dim code As String
    code = InputBox("Enter a Code")
    
    Do Until InputValid(code)
        code = InputBox("Enter a Code")
    Loop
        
    MsgBox ("Thank you for entering " & code)
End Sub

Function InputValid(argInput As String) As Boolean
    Const limitNum As Long = 3
    Const limitB As Long = 1
    Const limitExclaimation As Long = 1
    
    If Len(argInput) <> 7 Then
        
        Dim inputBytes() As Byte
        inputBytes = StrConv(argInput, vbFromUnicode)
                
        Dim countNum As Long
        Dim countB As Long
        Dim countExclaimation As Long
            
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To UBound(inputBytes)
            Select Case inputBytes(i)
                Case 33
                    countExclaimation = countExclaimation + 1
                Case 48 To 57
                    countNum = countNum + 1
                Case 66
                    countB = countB + 1
            End Select
            
            If countNum = limitNum And _
                countB = limitB And _
                countExclaimation = limitExclaimation Then
                InputValid = True
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

**Edit**
As suggested by GSerg, this is another method:

```
Sub btn_CheckCode2()
    Dim code As String
    code = InputBox("Enter a Code")
    
    Do Until InputValid(code)
        code = InputBox("Enter a Code")
    Loop
        
    MsgBox ("Thank you for entering " & code)
End Sub

Function InputValid(argInput As String) As Boolean
    Const limitNum As Long = 3
    Const limitB As Long = 1
    Const limitExclaimation As Long = 1
    Const limitInputLen As Long = 7

    If Len(argInput) <> limitInputLen Then
                    
        Dim countNum As Long
        Dim countB As Long
        Dim countExclaimation As Long
            
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To Len(argInput)
            Select Case Mid$(argInput, i, 1)
                Case "!"
                    countExclaimation = countExclaimation + 1
                Case 0 To 9
                    countNum = countNum + 1
                Case "B"
                    countB = countB + 1
            End Select
            
            If countNum = limitNum And _
                countB = limitB And _
                countExclaimation = limitExclaimation Then
                InputValid = True
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: How is operating in [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) easier than doing the same on the original string with `mid$` and comparing to actual letters?

Comment: @GSerg Well, I don't know. This method just came up first thing in my mind and it works so I didn't consider if it's easier/faster than other methods.

Comment: @Gserg Thanks for feedback, have edited to include your suggestion.